# Firebase functions build error when referencing multiple c# projects

Tags: c#, firebase, gcloud, serverless

I was able to deploy my firebase c# function with no issues, however, when i referenced another c# project so that i could utilize another object i get error saying project doesn't exist.

So was able to deploy following with no problem:

```
namespace CloudFunctions
{
    public class Login : IHttpFunction
    {
        public async Task HandleAsync(HttpContext context) {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

This class lives in a project called CloudFunctions. I added a project reference to a project called Services so that i could call the login service and i get the following error:

```
The referenced project '../Services/Services.csproj' does not exist
```

This is how i am deploying:

```
gcloud functions deploy login --entry-point CloudFunctions.Login --runtime dotnet3 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

I can't imagine we would be required to have everything in one project in order to deploy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make all of the projects available to the buildpack (i.e. deploy from the parent directory) but specify the project that contains the entry point as well, using the `GOOGLE_BUILDABLE` build-time environment variable.

From the [deployment documentation in the Functions Framework GitHub repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-dotnet/blob/master/docs/deployment.md):

> Real world functions are often part of a larger application which will usually contain common code for data types and common business logic. If your function depends on another project via a local project reference (a `<ProjectReference>` element in your .csproj file), the source code for that project must also be included when deploying to Google Cloud Functions. Additionally, you need to specify which project contains the function you wish to deploy.
>
> In a typical directory structure where all projects sit side-by-side within one top-level directory, this will mean you need to deploy from that top-level directory instead of from the function's project directory. You also need to use the `--set-build-env-vars` command line flag to specify the `GOOGLE_BUILDABLE` build-time environment variable. This tells the Google Cloud Functions deployment process which project to build and deploy. Note that the `GOOGLE_BUILDABLE` environment variable value is case-sensitive, and should match the directory and file names used.
>
> When deploying a function with multiple projects, it's important to make sure you have a suitable `.gcloudignore` file, so that you only upload the code that you want to. In particular, you should almost always include `bin/` and `obj/` in the `.gcloudignore` file so that you don't upload your locally-built binaries.

Sample deployment command line from the [`examples`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-dotnet/tree/master/examples) directory:

```sh
gcloud functions deploy multi-project \
  --runtime dotnet3 \
  --trigger-http \
  --entry-point=Google.Cloud.Functions.Examples.MultiProjectFunction.Function \
  --set-build-env-vars=GOOGLE_BUILDABLE=Google.Cloud.Functions.Examples.MultiProjectFunction
```

Comment: Does the .gcloudignore file belong in the parent directory?

Comment: @Maxqueue: Yes, it should be in the directory that you run `gcloud functions deploy` from. You can also specify the file to use with `--ignore-file`.

Comment: so in trying to set following: --set-build-env-vars=GOOGLE_BUILDABLE=./CloudFunctions/CloudFunctions.Login. I am in parent directory and function i want to deploy is in a folder called CloudFunctions directly inside parent. I tried with both the ./ and nothing in front of CloudFunctions?

Comment: getting  message=Build failed: ./CloudFunctions/CloudFunctions.Login does not exist; Error ID: 7c542a7d

Comment: I suspect you just want `--set-build-env-bars=GOOGLE_BUILDABLE=CloudFunctions` given that that's the directory containing the project. `CloudFunctions.Login` is the name of the class, not the project to be built. So for example, building the project from the command line normally (from the parent directory), you'd run `dotnet build CloudFunctions`. That's roughly what the buildpack needs to do too.

Comment: So no longer getting previous error. Now back to my original error using following: gcloud functions deploy login --entry-point CloudFunctions.Login --runtime dotnet3 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --set-build-env-vars=GOOGLE_BUILDABLE=CloudFunctions

The name 'Services' does not exist in the current context [/workspace/CloudFunctions/CloudFunctions.csproj]; Error ID: c0e07686

Services is a project that lives in directory along side CloudFunctions which is project CloudFunctions references

Comment: After cleaning solution it's working now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Doing so, in my case, solves the error, but results in a different error:
```ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: expected to find exactly one project file in directory UniversalEventDriven.Cache, found [].```
The project file is there. I don't know why it can't be found.

Comment: @Fabio: Please could you file a new issue with a minimal repro, either in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-dotnet or https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/buildpacks?

Comment: @JonSkeet I "solved" the issue by removing the ```.``` from the name of the directory targeted by the `GOOGLE_BUILDABLE`